# c# how to link 2 LinkedListNode?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I created a Linked list and a few nodes,  I want to link those node, kept getting this error message.

"
**Property or indexer System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<>.Next cannot be assigned to it is read only.**
"

```
        var link = new LinkedList<int>();
        var node1 = new LinkedListNode<int>(1);
        var node2 = new LinkedListNode<int>(2);
        var node3 = new LinkedListNode<int>(3);

        link.AddFirst(node1);
        link.AddFirst(node2);
        link.AddFirst(node3);

        node1.Next = node2;  ---> .next is read only
        node2.Next = node3;  ---> .next is read only
```

Comment: If you go to the definition of .Next, you'll see it only has a GET accessor. It cannot be assigned to. public LinkedListNode<T> Next { get; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add items to other items, but you should be adding them to the `LinkedList` itself, which you're already doing:

```
link.AddFirst(node1);
link.AddFirst(node2);
link.AddFirst(node3);
```

Are you trying to change their ordering?  It looks like that can only be done when adding them, based on [the methods available on `LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).  So you would want to do something like this instead:

```
link.AddFirst(node1);
link.AddAfter(node1, node2);
link.AddAfter(node2, node3);
```

Or, in your case, simply reversing the order of the calls to `.AddFirst()` will produce the same results:

```
link.AddFirst(node3);
link.AddFirst(node2);
link.AddFirst(node1);
```

This would add `node3` to the start of the list, then add `node2` to the start of the list (pushing `node3` to the second element), then add `node1` to the start of the list (pushing `node3` to the third element and `node2` to the second element).

Comment: You could also [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43ttx77w.aspx) an item from the list and then add it again in another position with either `AddBefore` or `AddAfter`.

Comment: @Renan: Indeed, between the various methods for adding and the various methods for removing items in the list can be ordered as needed.  It appears the OP was just hung up on the idea of changing an item's position by editing the item itself, which won't work.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the [AddAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hxfc7s5.aspx) or [AddBefore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw7zze8.aspx) methods of the list. With these you can insert items directly before or after a given item.

Unfortunately the `LinkedListNode<T>` class in .NET does not allow you to change the `Next` and `Previous` properties directly, since they don't have a `set` accessor.

If you want to change the ordering of the list, you'll also need to use the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43ttx77w.aspx) method to remove the item from its previous position. I recommend the following form:

```
LinkedListItem<T> foo = /*fetch your item here*/
LinkedListItem<T> bar = /*the one to come right after foo,
    as a result of running the code*/
list.Remove(foo);
list.AddBefore(bar, foo);
```

You could change that to insert after instead of inserting before.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to link them. When you invoke the AddFirst method, it automatically links them to the first node which then becomes the second node.

Comment: Yeah, but suppose she wants a new node in the middle of the list?

Comment: @Renan Then he should use `Insert` method

Comment: @Shaharyar [which `LinkedList` does not have.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb834fyk.aspx)

Comment: @Renan By `insert`, I meant insertion methods of `linked list`. E.g. `AddAfter` and `AddBefore`.